# Transferring data over web services

Tags: c#, web-services, windows-mobile, windows-ce

I need to transfer large amounts of look-up data from a remote database (oracle) to a windows mobile/ce device.  I would like to do this via web services if possible, but I'm trying to determine the best way to approach this.

I thought about serializing a Dataset, but I would like it with as little overhead as possible, so that's probably out of the equation.  It would also be good (if possible) to directly stream rather than cache and forward.

I'm currently writing it in an asmx service in 3.5, but happy to change to WCF if required.

Thanks

Comment: What's the definition of "best"? Fastest, easiest, most maintainable? Saying "all" doesn't help - there are lots of different options, and "best" is determining by trade-offs.

Comment: When you mean large amounts of data? Can you assign just specific information to the device?
 I have used POCO's to transfer information and just the needed data.